# Kirby CMS - add an image modified timestamp

Tags: php, kirby

I'm learning `Kirby CMS`.

I have a page displaying a series of images, I'm unsure how to get the date the image was uploaded.

I think it is something to do with the `$file` variable?:

```
$file->modified($format=false)
the last modified timestamp
```

here is my php loop:

```
<?php if($page->hasImages()): ?> 
    <ul class="gallery">
        <?php foreach($page->images() as $image): ?>
            <div class="gallerySegment">
            <h3 class="guidelineHead"><?php echo $image->title() ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $image->caption() ?></p>
            <li><img src="<?php echo $image->url() ?>" width="<?php echo $image->width() ?>" height="<?php echo $image->height() ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->title() ?>" /></li>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't possible by default in kirby 1. You could use the php-function [filetime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php).

In case of Kirby 2 you can write [$file->modified($format = false)](http://v2.getkirby.com/docs/cheatsheet#file) as in your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply do something like this within your loop.

```
<p>Uploaded at: <?php echo $image->modified('d. F Y'); ?></p>
```

This is available in Kirby 1 as well as in Kirby 2 as a single "image object" you have in your `$image` variable is always an extended "file object". That means you can use all file object  methods on image objects as well.

*If you need any information about how set the `$format` ('d. F Y'), you should have a look at [PHPs date() function explanation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)*